# Java Project to Executable Application

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, launch4j

I have developed a Java project in NetBeans integrated with SQLite database, I want now to export my project to be an executable file, so any user can use it by double-clicking without having Java installed, I had the JAR file and used Launch4j to convert JAR to exe file; yet it didn't work on user PCs, Is there any way to do it ? Thanks in advance

P.S: All users are on a shared drive, so they will be able to access the database normally

Comment: "without having Java installed" ... even if you make it an executable, Java will still be required. You can add a jre to your project. But why making it an exe? you are basically throwing away one of the the biggest advantages Java offers.

Comment: can you elaborate more please and explain to me how can i do this ?